# Microsoft Graph Planner resource not found

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I was doing a project for microsoft graph api.  All other was going great but When I do the planner simple get tasks. It returns this to me.

url: [`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/planner/tasks`](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/planner/tasks)

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "ResourceNotFound",
        "message": "Resource not found.",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "65e4a93a-949a-40d1-80fc-a6af0ec8d362",
            "date": "2020-01-21T12:09:18"
        }
    }
}
```

any solution for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the logs you are using a personal account. Currently, Planner is only available for organizational accounts (work or school) .

Answer (score 0):

`/planner/tasks/` is not a valid URI. You need to specify which Plan you want a [list the Tasks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/plannerplan-list-tasks?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) from:

```
/planner/plans/{plan-id}/tasks
```

Comment: from where I can get the plan-id.

Comment: `/planner/plans/`